# Multiple builds on a commit

Tags: git, svn, version-control, teamcity

We were previously using SVN but recently migrated to Git.

We have a monolithic repository for our enterprise application and have sub-applications as folders inside it.

We have multiple teamcity projects for each sub-application and this worked well till we were with SVN since we could specify folder in repository URL. However, Git doesn't allow including folders in repository URL so whenever something is committed in one sub-application, all other sub-applications are also built.

One way would be to take out sub-applications as new repositories but this initiative would take time. Is there some other solution?

Comment: Find someone who understands svn, git and your build environment to transition your build environment from svn to git.  If you want separate histories, separate the histories.  People trying to treat svn as if it were git will post similarly baffled questions.

Comment: Did the answer help you solve the problem? If yes, you can mark it as answer. And it will also benefit others who have similar questions.

Comment: Thank you all for your help.TeamCity support suggested using checkout rules to solve this thing and it worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

You shouldn't compare SVN to Git ever. This leads to this kind of confusion. While SVN is directory based, Git is project based, meaning that there is no way to commit/update the project partially. There is, nonetheless, a solution, but you dismissed it as time consuming (although I really think it would be a good investment): submodules.
You can read more [here](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules), but the gist of it is as follows:

> It often happens that while working on one project, you need to use another project from within it. [...] Git addresses this issue using submodules. Submodules allow you to keep a Git repository as a subdirectory of another Git repository. This lets you clone another repository into your project and keep your commits separate.

[Here](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule) is the complete documentation.

I would firmly advise you and your team to never compare SVN and Git. Even though they share a common goal, their usage, principles and workings, internal and external, make them incomparable, and more harmful than good.